# Declared Qt metatype not found in templated function

Tags: c++, qt

I get a compiler error when I try to create a QVariant from an enum in a templated function *after* I declare the metatype.  See the code below.

```
#include <QVariant>

struct ComboBox
{
   void addItem(const QString&, const QVariant&)
   {
      // ...
   }
};

enum MyEnum
{
   VALUE_ONE,
   VALUE_TWO
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyEnum)

template<class Map>
void populate(ComboBox& box, const Map& mapping)
{
   for (const auto& [value, description] : mapping)
   {
      box.addItem(description, QVariant::fromValue(value)); // error C2338: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system
   }
}

void foo(ComboBox& box)
{
   std::map<MyEnum, QString> MAP{ { VALUE_ONE, "one" }, { VALUE_TWO, "Two" } };
   populate(box, MAP);
}
```

This is with Qt 5.9.1 and Visual Studio 2017 (compiling 32-bit with /std:c++latest using the Qt VS2015 binaries).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with having a reference to my enum; I found three solutions:

1. Make a copy of `value` in the loop:

   ```
   const auto valueCopy = value;
   box.addItem(description, QVariant::fromValue(valueCopy));
   ```
2. Explicitly specify the template type of`fromValue`:

   ```
   using EnumType = decltype(mapping.begin()->first);
   box.addItem(description, QVariant::fromValue<EnumType>(value));
   ```
3. Not capture the pair by reference in the loop:

   ```
   for (const auto [value, description] : mapping)
   {
       box.addItem(description, QVariant::fromValue(value));
   }
   ```

But I cannot reproduce this problem outside of the templated function.